# A minimum string contain all the "n-combination"of n different elements(like the Haruhi Problem)

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

This string is not like the De Brujin sequence,010is equal to 100.
and there is a example. Just like the Haruhi Problem.
As a DoTa2 player, I like Carl very much. He is a great magician.Carl has three balls, which are Q ice, W thunder and E fire.If you press Q,there will be a ice ball around his head.But the number of the balls are always less than 3.Balls are saved in a queue.if you press QQWWWE,the last situation is WWE.Karl can use these balls to release tricks. For example, QQQ is a trick and QWE is another trick,which also equals to WEQ or EQW.Different combinations can produce different tricks, and there are 10 tricks in total.If you want to release the trick,you just need to press the R keyboard. When I first played Carl, I pressed wwqRwwwR. Later, I found that qwwRwR was better, which saved a lot of operation. So I thought, well, how many keystrokes does Carl have to press to finish all his skills in least steps?? Except for trick shortcut keys, press weqqqwwweeeq, and you can make up all tricks with 12 keys. If Carl has n balls, there are C (n-1, 2n-1) situations in the N-element combination. How many keystrokes need to press to remove the element fusion in the least steps?And how  many possible permutations are there with at least keystrokes? I think this problem is simpler than the minimum super permutation problem, but it is still too hard for me.

Comment: Did you look at the book *Magical Mathematics* by Diaconis and Graham?

Comment: @RichardStanley No, Professor.I haven't heard it before but I will search for it. Thank you very much,you are welcome.

Comment: Another reference for your type of question is https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/discrete-mathematics/vol/309/issue/17.